# Error while display data from from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Why I am getting this error?

Input string was not in a correct format.

I am trying to get data from selected column according to the ID.

Codes are:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Date,Day,Time,Total FROM RSVP WHERE Id = @dummy", conn);

    conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label2.Text;

    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows == false)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        Label8.Text = dr[0].ToString();
        Label9.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        Label10.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        Label11.Text = dr[3].ToString();
    }
```

Error at  line

```
  var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

My id is INT data type and it is the PK. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Value = int.Parse(Label2.Text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Add the value in paramter with [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) in following way:

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dummy",  Label2.Text);
```

There is `implicit conversion` while working with `AddWithValue`.

Comment: I am getting this error : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Label' to data type int.

Comment: That mean, Label2.Text has value "Label" which can't be converted to int....Debug your code n see the Label2.Text value....

Comment: In my previous page, there is a drop menu (username), when user click the username, the dropdown B will show ID of the username. Then hit save, hold the session of ID session, move the next page. Label2 will show the session of the ID. From session (ID), code above are used to show the data that belongs to ID.

Comment: Have you checked what's in Label2.Text while debugging?

Comment: Error at this line : cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text);

Comment: Instead of using Label.Text, use session value directly like Session["ID"] which you have used in assigning the Label2 value......

Comment: OMG! I feel like run to ur place and give u a hug! U just made my day!!!!!! Thanksssssssss

Answer (score 2):

Escape keywords in your query:

```
"SELECT [Date],[Day],[Time],Total FROM RSVP WHERE Id = @dummy"
```

Convert your data to and int.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Label2.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Label2.Text will not be an integer.

Convert it to an integer.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(Label2.Text);
```

Comment: What does Label2.Text have in it?

Comment: It has hold a session from previous page which is ID.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Sql Statement as:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Date],[Day],[Time],Total FROM RSVP WHERE Id = @dummy", conn);
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: I think you're missing parts of your answer here?

Comment: @Terric May I know what was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `Label2.Text` has a valid integer? Use `TryParse` to check if `label2.Text` has a valid value.

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(Label2.Text, out number);
```

It's much easier to use if the string might not actually contain an integer - it doesn't throw an exception so it's easier to recover from.